# Number of ways to select elements from n elements such that only consecutive elements are selected?

Tags: combinatorics

How can  I select elements from $n$ elements such that I select only consecutive elements?

For example:
Given a string $S=1001$,I can select $10,00,01,100,1001$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + (n - 1) = n (n - 1) / 2$
by the way the e.g. you gave should contain the combination 001 if I understand your problem correctly.
This is the simplest answer. If the characters are repeated, then the number of ways will differ. which definitely depends on the relative position of the repeated characters.