# Number of subequences that can be created from n elements

Tags: combinatorics

What is the formula to compute the number of non-empty subsequences (sequences of consecutive terms) that can be created from n elements?

Assuming we have a sequence of length 3, e.g. (a,b,c), we can create the following subsequences: {(a), (a,b), (a,b,c), (b), (b,c), (c)}. There are 6 subsequences.

What is the number of subsequences when the input sequence has length n?

I am aware of [Number of ways to select elements from n elements such that only consecutive elements are selected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856231/number-of-ways-to-select-elements-from-n-elements-such-that-only-consecutive-ele) but that does not seem to directly apply to this problem (?).

Comment: Consider the elements
$$X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5, X_6$$
In how many ways can you choose the first element of the subsequence? Let's say that you choose $X_3$ to be the first. Now you have

$$X_3, X_4, X_5, X_6$$

In how many ways can you choose the last element of the subsequence?

Comment: So it would be something like n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + (n-n)?

Comment: $n + n^2 - \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ ?

Comment: Please clarify whether a subsequence in which the terms may not be consecutive terms of the sequence are permitted.  For instance, did you deliberately omit the subsequence $(a, c)$ of $(a, b, c)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example that you gave yourself makes me think that you are after the number of non-empty substrings of a string of length $n$.

If this understanding is correct then there are: $$\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k+1)=\frac12n(n+1)$$such substrings.

Here $n-k+1$ is the number of substrings that have length $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Number of subsets of a set with $n$ elements = $2^n$

Total such combinations $(\text Excluding \space  \space \space\phi) =2^n-1$

Note : You missed  $(a,c)$ in your sub sequence.

**Edit :** If you want to find  sub-sequence of consecutive terms , then :

$$\text {Total   Terms} = n+(n-1)+(n-2) + ....+2+1$$
$$\text{For n = 3  } ,\space \space\space\space\text{Total Terms } \space=\space 3+2+1 \space\space=6$$

Comment: I don't think this is correct, because then in, in the example of the set $(a,b,c)$ you could create $(a,c)$ as a subsequence. But I think there should be no gaps, right? In this case, the $b$ has to be included, otherwise there is a gap.

Comment: What do you mean? It is not specified that the sub sequence should be consecutive terms.

Comment: I meant that subsequences are consecutive (as opposed to subsets).